# Width 100% not working on IE, paragraphs expanding on the whole page

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have paragraphs overflowing from a div, I want the text to wrap normally.

I saw a tutorial saying that flex-wrap doesn't work with width: 100% on IE.

```html
<div class="row bonASavoir rgpd">
  <div>
    <p>Paragraph </p>
    <p>Other paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

my css is global for a whole angular app, it says that the paragraphs should be width:100%.

It works on all browsers BUT IE.

The paragraphs expand on the whole screen!

If you know how I couls fix this!

Comment: You can use -ms-flex-wrap may help to fix the issue. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/hh673531(v=vs.85)

Comment: Please put your CSS and whatever HTML you need to illustrate your issue within your question.  Nothing overflows as you have it here.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the parent div and then please try this code..

**css**

```
.bonASavoir {
    width: 20px;
}
.bonASavoir p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```